# How to differentiate between the Actual North Pole and South pole of any magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

Simulate a magnet sticking to a metal door. The side that is against the door, means that side is the pulling side, and must be the inwards movement of a toroidal magnetic field, pulling the object inwards resulting in getting stuck to the object! Does this mean, the side that is against the object is the side where the field goes in through the magnet and will always be the actual South pole of any magnet? When the magnet is flipped onto the object, the field is in the opposite direction pushing against the object, which will be the North pole of that magnet. Does this mean that when holding a magnet and you can diffirentiate between the actual physical pushing and pulling side of a magnet, them to know that the pushing side must be North and the pulling side must be South? This has Nothing to do with: Stringing the magnet and it will find magnetic North or South and zero to do with earths magnetic field direction, but everything to do with the toroidal magnetic field of the magnet itself  and which direction the magnets toroidal field flows?

Answer (score 0):

The convention is that the north pole flips to the north due to the magnetic field of the earth. In other words: The only convention that we have is: earth's geographic north = earth's magnetic south and vice versa.  So in order to correctly label your magnet, you have to figure out how it interacts with the magnetic field of the earth. Or, if you have another magnetic that is labeled correctly, you can check which end of your magnet sticks to that magnet. If it sticks to S, then that side is N etc.